# Testing Spring Boot API results in HTTP 405 (Method not Allowed) on PUT

Tags: tomcat, http-status-code

I created an API which I deployed to Tomcat Server. During development, I would start the application from Eclipse and test the end point using Postman. From Eclipse, the application runs fine. I would see my bot (created with Selenium WebDriver) starting, hitting the targeted pages, clicking the scripted elements, and finishing the process.

I modified the POM to build a WAR file which I manually deployed using Tomcat Manager App page. The WAR deployed and it is running fine as far as I can tell. I decided to run the same test using Postman; obviously changing "localhost" to the actual IP address and port.  Unfortunately, I get this HTTP 405 error and I do not know why. I assume that something needs to be configured in Tomcat but I have no clue as to what specifically I need to do.

I configured Tomcat according to this and still no luck: http://www.codereye.com/2010/12/configure-tomcat-to-accept-http-put.html

Comment: Need more details on the 405 error - looks like the call might be faulty. Call and response messages would also help with debugging.

Comment: I have no more details to give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat by default is not enabled for HTTP PUT command.

I had to configure Tomcat by modifying the web.xml and the tomcat-users.xml files.

### Changes to web.xml file

1. Needed to add `readonly=false` parameter

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>readonly</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
```

2. Needed to add a security constraint for the role

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Demo App</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>#####</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

### Changes to the tomcat-users.xml file

1. Needed to add a user and role to match the added security constraint

```
<user name="#####" password="#####" roles="#####" />
```